# Paho MQTT library names

Tags: mqtt, paho

I found list of paho MQTT libraries installed in Linux:

```
libpaho-mqtt3a.so -> libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1 -> libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1.3
libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1.3
libpaho-mqtt3as.so -> libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1 -> libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1.3
libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1.3
libpaho-mqtt3c.so -> libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1 -> libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.3
libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.3
libpaho-mqtt3cs.so -> libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1 -> libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.3
libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.3
```

I understand that file names with ending with `as` means `asynchronous`. But what about `a`, `c`, `cs`?

What they are used for

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [the readme](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c#libraries):

> paho-mqtt3a - asynchronous (MQTTAsync)
> paho-mqtt3as - asynchronous with SSL (MQTTAsync)
> paho-mqtt3c - "classic" / synchronous (MQTTClient)
> paho-mqtt3cs - "classic" / synchronous with SSL (MQTTClient)

Hopefully this answers the question; if more info is needed there is [a link](https://modelbasedtesting.co.uk/2013/10/13/which-paho-mqtt-c-api-to-use-and-some-history/), just below the above, to a document that explains the which to use and why in some detail (but is somewhat outdated!).